# How to set the offset for the components name in Eagle schematic?

Tags: components, eaglecad

I am using Eagle 7.1.0. In the eagle schematic the component name is started by default by 1, 2, 3, …

For example I want to use an offset of 100. Eagle should give the component a name like 101, 102, 103, …

How can I create an offset so that Eagle starts numbering from different value?

Comment: I am not aware of any setting to define component's offset in advance,  "Tools > Renumber parts.." may do what you need (if you don't have additional requirements) when your schematic is done

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how to modify Eagle itself to change its behavior as you describe, but this ULP script named [renumber_by_page.ulp](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B4fBtTjSpEUlNjAzV0R0N3RtXzg/view?usp=sharing), written by Morten Leikvoll,  will rename all components in the format:

```
<prefix><page#><localpageindex>

Example:
5 R's on sheet1 will be renamed R100-R105
5 C's on sheet1 will be renamed C100-C105
5 R's on sheet2 will be renamed R200-R205
```

If you have more than 100 R's on one sheet, the 100th will be renamed R1100,
which could be mis-interpreted as an R on page 11, but normally you don't have
that many resistors on one sheet.

Special case, if your components have a name like ICxxxA (i.e. one section of a package), the suffix A will be added to the new name, so IC1A becomes IC101A.

I tried this on Eagle 7.3.0 and it seems to work fine.